# ASP.NET MVC - URL Routing parameter question

Tags: asp.net-mvc, url-routing, asp.net-mvc-routing

I have this route declaration:

```
routes.MapRoute(
                // Route name
                "WhiteLabelPartners",
                // URL with parameters
                "partners/{partnerName}/{controller}/{action}/{id}",
                // Parameter defaults
                new { partnerName = "", controller = "", action = "index", id = UrlParameter.Optional }
                );
```

When I try this URL:

```
/partners/a/savings/index/1
```

...it works fine. The index action of the Savings controller is hit.

But, when I try this URL:

```
/partners/a/savings/index
```

I get a "not found".

If I have a UrlParameter.Optional for the {id} parameter, why is it still being required?

Could anyone explain? How can I make the {id} parameter optional?

Thanks

Comment: If you request `/partners/a/savings/index/` does it work?

Comment: No Tejs, it doesn't work, I get a "not found" too.

Comment: Specify a default controller in your route defaults. It should land you on the default controller if the route is matching.

Comment: can you post your action method?

Comment: I tried that but it didn't work. Very strange.

Comment: It's a standard: public virtual ActionResult Index() { ... }

Comment: why is it virtual? also your method should be public ActionResult Index(int? id)

Comment: @achinth It should be `ActionResult Index(string partnerName, int? id) {}`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Make sure your Index Action does not expect a parameter.

If, on your controller, your Index action looks like this :
**public ActionResult Index(int id)**

it will need a param to be passed in the ID field, as you are not providing a default value in the route. That's probably why you are getting the 'not found'error as it cannot find a matching action. It is expecting :

**public ActionResult Index()**

You could leave the Index() action without a parameter and from within the Index() action, retrieve the value of the passed in 'id' parameter, if any via :

**RouteData.Values["id"]**

to use it.
Let us know if that works for you.

(note: i wanted to post a comment like tejs(but dont see a link to add comment?!), to ask you to show your Index method signature on the controller, so please do include that in the question.)

Comment: you can use public ActionResult Index(int? id) - this make id optional

Comment: Thanks. I think my problem is something with the {partnerName} parameter. When I attach the debugger and try the URL /partners/a/savings/index, I get an exception, Not found. When inspecting the requestContext.RouteData.Values, I can see keys "controller", "action" and "id". Then "a", "savings" and "index" as values. It's not recognizing the "partnerName" parameter. I changed my action method to: public virtual ActionResult Index(string partnerName, string id) {}  but still no luck.

Comment: Found the problem: there was an Area registered with the same name of "partners" and it was being chosen, for the route, instead of my declared route.